# Relation about vector norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Given a square matrix A. What property A should satisfy such that:

$ \|x \|< \|y \| $ implies $ \|Ax \|<  \|Ay \| $ for any vectors $x,y$?

How can I use the decomposition of x and y into eigenvectors of A, to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If $A$ is unitary the implication clearly holds

Comment: if $A$ is a nonzero scalar multiple of a unitary matrix the implication also holds

Comment: I wonder whether the converse is true :)

Comment: Did you have a particular norm in mind?

Comment: yes, the Euclidian norm.

Comment: A priori, there is no reason to presume that $x,y$ can be decomposed into eigenvectors of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ be two eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$, such that $\mathbf{Ax}=\lambda_1 \mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{Ay}=\lambda_2 \mathbf{y}$ and $|\lambda_1| > |\lambda_2|$. Also, presume that $$0<\|\mathbf{y}\|-\|\mathbf{x}\|=a < \left(1-\frac{|\lambda_2|}{|\lambda_1|}\right) \|\mathbf{y}\|.$$
Now, $$\|\mathbf{Ax}\|=|\lambda_1|\|\mathbf{x}\| < \|\mathbf{Ay}\|=|\lambda_2|\|\mathbf{y}\| \implies |\lambda_1|(\|\mathbf{y}\|-a)<|\lambda_2|\|\mathbf{y}\|,$$ which implies
$$a >\left(1-\frac{|\lambda_2|}{|\lambda_1|}\right) \|\mathbf{y}\|,$$
which is a contradiction.

Therefore, $|\lambda_1| = |\lambda_2|$. That is, all the eigen values of $A$ must be equal in magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

It is straightforward to show that $\|x\|= \|y\|$ then $\|Ax\|= \|Ay\|$.

Let $\mu = \|A e_1\|$, then we have $\|x\| = \| {1\over \mu} Ax \|$
for all $x$ from which it follows that ${1\over \mu} A$ is unitary.

(The latter follows from the polarisation identity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity#Formula.)